How do i know the last selected value in the SegmentedButton with multiSelectEnabled?
The problem is that it stores as a Set, and onSelectionMethod returns a Set, not a unique value. Getting the last or first value does not work because when you disable a value that was added a few steps ago, it is removed from its current position in the set. Any ideas? (I am trying to write a logic where the first two values cannot be enabled at the same time, and the last is enabled, it disables all other properties.)
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTestSelectedButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTestSelectedButton({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyTestSelectedButton> createState() => _MyTestSelectedButtonState();
}

class _MyTestSelectedButtonState extends State<MyTestSelectedButton> {
  Set<int> selectedValues = {1};
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SegmentedButton(
          multiSelectionEnabled: true,
          style: ButtonStyle(visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: -4)),
          showSelectedIcon: false,
          segments: List.generate(
              4, (index) => ButtonSegment(value: index, label: Text('$index'))),
          selected: selectedValues,
          onSelectionChanged: (newSelectedValues) {
            setState(() {
              selectedValues = newSelectedValues;
              print(newSelectedValues);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Solved.
I have created 2 sets, and just checking the difference between the old one and new one. It works as it should.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTestSelectedButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTestSelectedButton({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyTestSelectedButton> createState() => _MyTestSelectedButtonState();
}

class _MyTestSelectedButtonState extends State<MyTestSelectedButton> {
  Set<int> selectedValues = {1};
  Set<int> oldValues = {};

  void getLastSelectedValue(Set<int> newValues) {
    if (oldValues.isEmpty) oldValues = selectedValues;
    int lastSelectedValue = oldValues
        .difference(newValues)
        .union(newValues.difference(oldValues))
        .first;
    oldValues = newValues;
    print(lastSelectedValue);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SegmentedButton(
          multiSelectionEnabled: true,
          style: ButtonStyle(visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: -4)),
          showSelectedIcon: false,
          segments: List.generate(
              4, (index) => ButtonSegment(value: index, label: Text('$index'))),
          selected: selectedValues,
          onSelectionChanged: (newSelectedValues) {
            setState(() {
              getLastSelectedValue(newSelectedValues);
              selectedValues = newSelectedValues;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

